# conditional disaggregation of coarse raster to high resolution raster

Tags: r, terra, rasterize

I have a raster that tells me fraction burnt area in a cell

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 128, 256, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1.40625, 1.400437  (x, y)
extent      : -180.7031, 179.2969, -89.62795, 89.62795  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : BurntArea.tif 
name        : BurntArea 
min value   :       0.0000000 
max value   :       0.8538834
```

I have another raster which is a fine resolution and a binary 1 and 0. 1 implies that pixel
is burnable and 0 implies it is unburnable

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 64800, 129600, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.002777778, 0.002777778  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : binary_raster 
name        : binary_raster 
min value   :       0 
max value   :       1
```

I want to disaggregate `burnt area` to the `binary` layer to only those cells which are burnable i.e. have a value of 1. When disaggregating burnt area to the binary layer 1, I need to distribute it equally to all cells equal to 1. I am thinking the best way to do this is:

1. Do a zonal stats first to calculate number of burnable pixels (binarylayer = 1) in each coarse burnt area cell

   ```
   count_brpixel <- terra::zonal(binary_raster, BurntArea, fun = "sum", as.raster = T)
   ```
2. Divide the burnt area by total number of burnable pixels such that I get burnt area per burnable pixel

   ```
   burnt_per_pixel <- BurntArea/count_brpixel
   ```
3. Disaggregate burnt_per_pixel at the same resolution as the binary_raster

   ```
   res_drop <- res(binary_raster)[1]/res(BurntArea)[1]
   burnt_per_pixel_disagg <- terra::disagg(burnt_per_pixel, fact = res_drop)
   ```
4. Multiply burnt_per_pixel_disagg with binary raster.

   ```
   final_file <- burnt_per_pixel_disagg * binary_raster
   ```

The final_file contains the burntarea in a high resolution

I am actually stuck on step (1) where I get the `Error: [zonal] extents do not match`. At this point, I don't even know if the rest of steps will generate any error or whether this is right way to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the first hurdle (1), make an empty rast with resolution of binary and extent of burnt (and crs) as binary2 - see ?rast signature 'missing', and  `aligned_I_can_use_binary <- terra::resample(binary, binary2)`, use the resulting in your terra::focal. What data are you using?

Comment: For the burnt area, I am using the CMIP6 GCM data. For binary 0/1 mask, it is a derived raster from 300m Copernicus LULC but each LULC is classified as either burnable or unburnable

Comment: And date of data downloaded, approximately?

Comment: A week back I downloaded it

Comment: For Copernicus, I calculated it myself i.e. derived the binary layer myself

Comment: The answers to this question, over at the GIS platform, might do the trick with little need for adaptation: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423291/how-can-i-both-resample-and-aggregate-a-raster-using-terra